# Aws - Ubuntu - Cron job not running

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, cron

I have a aws ec2 server with ubuntu on it.

I did the following to set my cron

`sudo crontab -e`

`15,45 * * * * ubuntu /usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null https://mywebsite.com/cron/`

But its not running.

Comment: what are you expecting to be running with what results?

Comment: I want to run a website link `https://mywebsite.com/cron/` at every 15, 45 of the clock like `1:15, 1:45, 2:15, 2:45` This link does multiple job regarding mailing and mysql data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the username from the cron line and it should start working.